# How to show each `td` content when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Each appended `tr` tag will have a `td` list with a different data. So, I want to edit the selected `tr` tag and showing all `td` content in the `console` when a button is clicked. I think this is very easy but I had no idea about this before, Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$('.add-el').click(function(){
  $('tbody').append(`<tr>
    <td id="text">red</td>
    <td id="text">Small</td>
    <td id="text">6</td>
    <td id="text">$10.99</td>
    <td id="text">2021-03-23</td>
    <td>
      <button id="edit">Edit</button>
      <button id="remove">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>`);
});

$('tbody').on('click','#edit', function(){
  // Ex: console.log(I want to show here all td content);
})

$("tbody").on('click', '#remove', function () {                
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-el">Add Element</button>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery methods `.closest()` and `.children()` and pass in the element types you are targeting. You can then spread the returned `HTMLCollection` into an `array` (`[...HTMLCollection]` => this returns an array) so you can iterate over them with a `forEach` loop and print them one by one or do any other operations you wish.

You had a few issues where multiple elements had the same `id`. When you need that then rather use `classes` since `ids` need to be unique.

```js
$('.add-el').click(function(){
  $('tbody').append(`<tr>
    <td class="text">red</td>
    <td class="text">Small</td>
    <td class="text">6</td>
    <td class="text">$10.99</td>
    <td class="text">2021-03-23</td>
    <td>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>`);
});

$('tbody').on('click','.edit', function(){
  let children = [...$(this).closest('tr').children('td.text')];
  
  children.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item.innerHTML);
  });
});

$('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function () {                
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-el">Add Element</button>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

You can also use the jQuery `.text()` method:

```
$('tbody').on('click','.edit', function(){
  console.log( $(this).closest('tr').children('td.text').text() );
});
```

but that will make the output look like:

```
redSmall6$10.992021-03-23
```

Comment: Done! Your answer works fine with my project. @Ivan86 Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**IDs must be unique**, if not they are no longer Ids

I'd assign the event handler to the `tr` then check the event target. We are interested in working with the `tr` after all.

```js
$('.add-el').click(function(){
  $('tbody').append(`<tr>
    <td class="text">red</td>
    <td class="text">Small</td>
    <td class="text">6</td>
    <td class="text">$10.99</td>
    <td class="text">2021-03-23</td>
    <td>
      <button class="edit">Edit</button>
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>`);
});

//Event handler for tr
$('tbody').on('click','tr', function(event){
   //Was the remove button clicked
   if(event.target.matches(".remove")) {
    //Remove this row
    $(this).remove();
   //Was the edit button clicked
   }else if(event.target.matches(".edit")) {
    //Iterate the text elements
    $(this).find(".text").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).text());
      //Do whatever else you need here
    });
    
    //Aletranatively use map
    let cellVals = $.map($(this).find(".text"), function(e){
     return $(e).text(); });    
    console.log(cellVals.join("|"));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-el">Add Element</button>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```